What movie has a classroom clock tick backwards?
I'm remembering a moment that I thought was from Ferris Bueller's Day Off, but I can no longer seem to find it, so perhaps I'm thinking of the wrong movie.
A high-school student is anxiously awaiting the end of class (or a timed exam), staring intently at the clock.  The last minute seems interminable.  When the clock hand does finally move, it first moves backward a bit before ticking forward to the next minute.  (That was a quirk of that style of classroom clock, but it's greatly exaggerated in the scene.)  When it unexpectedly moves backward, the anxious student shouts in frustration, disrupting the class (or exam) just before the bell rings.
Can you identify the movie?  If it is from Ferris Bueller's Day Off, when does it occur in the story and which student has the outburst (Cameron?).

I think there's a scene with a clock in Better Off Dead but I'm not sure

Notably, Ferris never went into school in Ferris Bueller's Day Off. The closest he got was the main entrance, although we do see him in school in the TV spin-off; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ToEgs_L2K94

3 O’Clock High obviously has clock shots, but I don’t recall this one.

This is Risky Business (1983).
Tom Cruise's character is sitting in class. The clock ticks backwards and he has an outburst around 46 minutes into the film. The bell rings a few seconds later and they exit the class.


Could this be The Simpsons, specifically Season 3 episode 4: Bart The Murderer?
Bart is watching the clock and it goes backwards.



